# What's the equivalent for getting the list of constructors in .NET Standard / Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm trying to upgrade my .NET 4 project to .NETStandard and Core, but unable to find the equivalent for this:-

```
        var ctors = typeof(T).GetConstructors();
```

GetConstructors is a part of reflection, so seems like the support is intentionally lacking or moving...

Thanks.
Simon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In .NET standard /Core a lot of reflexion api are moved to a specific package (system.reflection). This package provide the extension method `GetTypeInfo` on Type class.

```
typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors;
```

Comment: Yes, GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors is the answer. Returns ConstructorInfo enumeration from the property.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy - just add `GetTypeInfo()`:

```
var ctors = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors();
```